# PHP my admin not working after reinstalled WAMP

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, wampserver

Wamp, phpMyAdmin and stuff worked perfectly until i upgraded it from phpmyadmin4.0.4 to phpmyadmin4.1.14.

Now i get 'You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin/ on this server.' message...

myPhpAdmin.conf is here:

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin4.1.14/">
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
   AllowOverride all
  <IfDefine APACHE24>
    Require local
  </IfDefine>
  <IfDefine !APACHE24>
    Order Deny,Allow
      Deny from all
      Allow from localhost ::1 127.0.0.1
    </IfDefine>
  php_admin_value upload_max_filesize 128M
  php_admin_value post_max_size 128M
  php_admin_value max_execution_time 360
  php_admin_value max_input_time 360
</Directory>
```

I haven't found solution for this...
Thanks

EDIT 1:

Now, here is a strange thing. Apache error logs outputs this when i try to access `http://localhost/phpmyadmin/` :

```
[Thu May 28 17:52:12.600573 2015] [authz_core:error] [pid 5872:tid 800] [client ::1:50257] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: C:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin4.0.4, referer: http://localhost/
```

As you can se client denied by server configuration on wrong folder (server outputs phpmyadmin with 4.0.4 version - according to phpmyadmin syntax)!

I think that is wrong, but how can i change that server configuration?

Comment: how are set the permissions to that folder? (ls -la on linux)
also try sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin /var/www/ 
or sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin /var/www/html/ if you are in the new ubuntu

Comment: How come I can't find phpmyadmin version 4.1.14 on the phpmyadmin downloads page? http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/downloads.php

Comment: Well, installed last version of Wamp on http://www.wampserver.com/en/download-wampserver-64bits/ and phpMyAdmin version is 4.1.14 (as i can read in phpmyadmin.conf)

Comment: @SpongePablo WAMPServer! The W stands for WINDOWS

Answer (score 0):

The first line of `\wamp\alias\phpmyadmin.conf` should also be amended to match the new folder location of your upgraded phpmyadmin

```
Alias /phpmyadmin "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin4.1.14/"
```

Did you do that?

Comment: And did you restart Apache?

Comment: Did you upgrade phpmyadmin or the whole of WAMPServer

Comment: @MarcDelisle Restarted.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Whole wampserver upgraded.

Comment: Would have been useful to have said that rather than making it sound like you just upgraded phpMyAdmin!

Comment: Did you just install 2.5 over your 2.4 or did you do it properly? See [Installing a new release of WAMPServer](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,123606) on the WAMPServer forum.

Comment: Well it was my mistake. Had to open WAMP as admin... That solved the problem. Thanks anyway

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem and I just uninstalled everything again and then installed it, but this time ran the install as Administrator. That actually fixed it. Hope it helps.